# Update BLE broadcast message at low latency

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I want to use RPis to broadcast every 50ms a new updated message of just a few bytes, for its listeners to receive. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to create some kind of BLE beacon which would allow you to send a small amount of data as either Service Data or Manufacturer data. Depending what else you want the advertisement to contain, then there are about 20 bytes maximum.

The easiest way to do this on Linux is with the BlueZ Advertising API which is documented at:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/advertising-api.txt

There is an overly complicated example of how to use the API at:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-advertisement

So part of it is definitely possible to do with Python on Linux. The next part of your question was about updating the content of the advertisement every 50ms. The BlueZ API wasn't designed to have the content updated regularly.  To do that with the BlueZ API the advertisement needs to be removed and replaced with a new one.

The Bluetooth spec says an BLE advertisement can have a fixed interval from 20ms to 10.24 seconds, in steps of 0.625ms, plus a pseudo-random value from 0ms to 10ms that is automatically added. This randomness helps reduce the possibility of collisions between advertisements of different devices (if they fell in the same rate, they could interfere more easily). This is just another technique BLE uses to improve robustness.

The reason I mention this is because the BlueZ API doesn't give the user control over that interval as a result every 50ms might be a little quicker than the default values used by BlueZ but some experimentation should quickly reveal what's possible.

You can setup advertisements from the command line using the `bluetoothctl` tool. An example of sending a [Eddystone URL](https://github.com/google/eddystone/tree/master/eddystone-url) beacon:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothctl 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# advertise.uuids feaa
[bluetooth]# advertise.service 0xfeaa 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x62 0x6c 0x75 0x65 0x74 0x6f 0x6f 0x74 0x68 0x00
[bluetooth]# advertise.discoverable on
[bluetooth]# advertise on
[CHG] Controller B8:27:EB:22:57:E0 SupportedInstances: 0x04
[CHG] Controller B8:27:EB:22:57:E0 ActiveInstances: 0x01
Advertising object registered
UUID: (feaa)
UUID: Google(0xfeaa)
  10 00 00 62 6c 75 65 74 6f 6f 74 68 00           ...bluetooth.   
Tx Power: off
Name: off
Appearance: off
Discoverable: on
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
Changing discoverable on succeeded
[CHG] Controller B8:27:EB:22:57:E0 Discoverable: yes
[bluetooth]#
```